# how to add authorization header to IO.socket call in android

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio, sails.js, io-socket

```
 JSONObject getobj = new JSONObject();

        postobj.put("url", String.format("/user"));

        Log.d("Get MEthod", getobj.toString() + ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Get Message " + socket.connected());

        Log.d(TAG, " the meessage url " + getobj.toString());

        socket.emit("get",getobj, new Ack() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {

                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) args[0];

                Log.d("GET CHAT MEESSAGE ", obj.toString() + ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> with in call method Get Message " + socket.connected());

            }
        });
```

/*I got Bellow response*\

```
   {
   "body": {
      "err": "No Authorization header was found"
     },
   "headers": {

   },
   "statusCode": 401
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how i add authorization token for Socket connection, Hope this helps

```
IO.Options options = new IO.Options(); 
options.forceNew = true;                        
options.reconnectionAttempts = Integer.MAX_VALUE;                    
options.timeout = 10000;    
options.query = "token=" + "your_authorization_code";
```

Comment: I have already tried but not working bro please give another idea

Answer (score 2):

For passing header is IO.socket we need to create Options for that

```
        val options = Options
            .builder()
            .setExtraHeaders(
                mapOf("Authorisation" to listOf("TOKEN"))
            )
```

and then pass it to IO.socket

```
IO.socket("URL", options)
```